# How to run XMLHttpRequest in a loop properly

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am running XMLHttpRequest inside `.map()` and it work fine.

```
   list.map(function(file) {
     const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {}
     xhr.onerror = function () {}
     xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', (e) => {}
     xhr.send(file);
   }
```

However problem is that this loop start all `xhr.send()` simultaneously.
What should I do to make this iterations occurs one by one.
When one request complete next to start?

Comment: You should make use of promises and wait until one has finished before starting the next one using [**`.then()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then). However, considering you're only **sending** files, not sure why you would need to worry about them being concurrent :)

Comment: My main problem is progress. I have progress bar that I update and when all happen in the same time my bar go back and forth and I am trying to make it update without going back

Comment: Then your problem is not "how to run XHRs", but "how to update progressbar" =))

Comment: I thought running one by one could solve that

Comment: Running one by one will hardly help. I think you have to calculate the total progress and update progressbar with it.

Comment: And how can I calculate it?

Comment: So, did you want to kick off all XHR's and then have the progress bar show overall progress? Seeing as you are doing an upload, you know beforehand the total size you are sending, so the calculation is pretty easy - p.s. why are you using `.map`? it's not like you return anything

Comment: I return promise around this loop is promise.all

Answer (score 0):

This is a classical question in the world of asynchronous programming and developers have been thinking long and hard on different ways to achieve what you want.

The hype is now in functional programming so let me show you a couple of the tricks. Btw, this solutions allows you to sequence *any* collection of asynchronous tasks to be executed one after another.

First of, you want to use `fetch()` instead of `XMLHttpRequest`. Then, you want to use techniques called `apply`, `compose` and `thunking` like so:

```
const urls = ['https://www.google.com', 'https://medium.com'];

let progress = 0;

const fetchHtml = url => {
  return fetch(url).then(resp => resp.text());
};

const updateProgressbar = (html) => {
  console.log('Update progressbar!');
  return ++progress/urls.length;
};

const thunk = (f, ...args) => () => f(...args);
const apply = (acc,val) => acc.then(val);
const compose = (...funcs) => x => funcs.reduce(apply, Promise.resolve(x));
const sequence = (f, inputs) => compose(...inputs.map(input => thunk(f, input)))();

sequence(compose(fetchHtml, updateProgressbar, console.log), urls);
```